# This is vs I am [introduce self sms/whatsapp/email]

Tags: phrase-usage

How can I introduce myself when I text to someone who knows me for the first time after I got her number or when I use a different phone number or when I send an email?

Usually, I use "**I am (Igor).**"

Is it correct?
How is the difference from "**this is**"?

I suppose just of "feeling" (AmE and BrE).

Answer (score 2):

*This is X* (or just *It's X*) are more natural when introducing yourself to someone who knows you, but doesn't know you're the one speaking or texting.

*I am X* or *My name is X* are - in my opinion - better used when introducing yourself to someone who doesn't know you, or doesn't know your name.

A good way to remember that is to consider which question you've been asked - an English speaker would typically ask *Who's that?*or *Who's speaking?* in the former case, and *Who are you?* in the latter.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any difference between "this is" vs "it's"? And, do you think that there is a real difference between "I am" and "this is", because  https://www.lifewire.com/introduce-yourself-when-sending-initial-instant-message-1172468 they seem to have the same meaning.

Comment: Moreover, if I receive i call and I don't know the number, I should ask "Who are you?" and how should he/she answer?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: @Igor89 Not much of a difference between "this is" and "it's", the former is slightly more formal. And both "I am" and "this is" mean similar things, but "I am Igor" will sound a bit odd to someone who knows you. And if you get a call, the safest question is "Who's speaking?" - "Who is it?" and "Who's that?" are also pretty acceptable.

Comment: Also, who is it? And, what do you think about my link? Because it seems to use in the same manner "I am" and "It's".

Comment: @Igor89 neither of the examples in the link is wrong, although with no other context I'd assume the recipient is more familiar with Brad (who introduces himself using *it's*) than Joan (who uses *I am*). Then again, it's not a hard rule - the only case I'd really oppose would be using *I am X* towards a friend.

Comment: You are fantastic... Thank you. If a met a man during a meeting and then I write him a sms giving my number (or email etc) can I use "I am" because he isn't a friend? Is it right?

Comment: So, If I have well understood, My name is the more formal I am formal This is-it's to use with a friend, family etc. Right? But, If I met a man during a meeting and then I write him a sms giving my number (or email etc) can I use "I am" because he isn't a friend? Is it right?

Comment: May i have more info about the difference between these expressions?

Comment: @Igor89 "My name is" is the more formal "I am" in this context, that's right. "This is" and "It's" you should always use with people you know well. If you only met someone once, "I am" is okay, although "This is" is still more natural to me. If you've never met someone, "I am" is slightly better, although "This is" is also acceptable.

Comment: I was thinking about your answer. I don't find two different situations where I use "who is speakin?" and "who are you?". If I receive a message and I haven't got the number, I think:" who are you?"